# how to do stratified sampling in loop?

Tags: r, loops, splitstackshape

I have two datasets. One that I need to sample from and the other that specified number of records to sample from each strata. I want to sample repeatedly with specified sample size until the sample dataframe reaches X number of records. How can I sample in loops? I am currently using stratified function from package splitstackshape?